# .htaccess redirect loop when Redirect and RewriteRule together

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm attempting the following in an HTACCESS file:

I want to 301 redirect this --> http://www.domain.com/somepage.php?page=foo

to this --> http://www.domain.com/my-pretty-url/

This works fine when I alter internal links on the site to read how I want and I DO NOT use the R=301 flag:

```
RewriteRule ^my-pretty-url/$ /index\.php?page=foo [L]
```

BUT... the hitch here is I also want to 301 Redirect any external requests to the server, which when I handle that it puts me in a redirect loop.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=foo$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.domain.com/my-pretty-url/? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^my-pretty-url/$ /index\.php?page=foo [L]
```

The RewriteCond rules don't work by themselves, only the single RewriteRule at the bottom works by itself for internal rewrites, but it doesn't handle outside requests.

Obviously, if I have both together, it's creating a loop.  How do I get around this??

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following to prevent the looping

```
#prevent internal redirects, and prevent loop
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=foo$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.domain.com/my-pretty-url/? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^my-pretty-url/$ /index\.php?page=foo [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but I think I might've left out a detail here...  The page being called is in a CMS, and the page can't really be renamed, so the "page=" parameter is required.  The solution you and I both have are assuming the page was actually renamed to the pretty URL (true?).

Comment: @GregR. It is ideal, but not necessary to rename the page to a pretty url. If a user clicks on the old page with page param, the first rule will redirect them to the pretty url. The second rule will then rewrite it back to the old url (just like the CMS expects), and the additional `RewriteCond` will prevent a loop.

Comment: I left out the "?" at the end of the pretty url rewrite rule. Once I put that in, It totally worked. Thanks!!