# apache - rewritten URL gets redirected wrong

Tags: apache, redirect, url-rewriting, conditional-statements

i'm having a problem with redirection / rewrite rules.
Here is my **htaccess file**: http://pastebin.com/KJKFGgiH .

## Context

I want to use rewritten url on my website that is already online.

## What I want is

When someone asks for `/main.php` (old URL), i want him to get redirected on `/en/` (New URL), and then apache sends him the result of `main.php?lang=en` (due to the rewrite rule on line 7). Also, I don't want the user to ever see the `/main.php` URL, that's why I didn't use a rewrite rule instead of a redirect. (see after)

## what actually happens is

1. when I ask for the `/main.php` page
2. apache redirects my browser to `/en/`
3. when it gets my `/en/` request, it rewrites the URl into `/main.php?lang=en` (which is the expected behaviour)
4. then apache could just stop there and treat the `/main.php?lang=en` request, but no, it splits the URL into `/main.php` and `args=lang=en`, and tries to rewrite and redirect the new URL it have (ie `/main.php`)
5. and when it finds the "`redirect /main.php /en/`" line, it applies it, and replaces `/main.php` by `/en/`
6. then it gathers the url again, giving `/en/?lang=en`
7. it redirects my browser to that wrong URL

Here is the error log on which you can follow the explanations I just gave (I recommend you to download it and open it with notepad++ or any software without automatic line break) : http://pastebin.com/Z9q2pry6.

## What the solution would be

Apache has to apply the redirect directive only once.

### Solution I tried number 1 : using 'if'

I figured out I could try to modify the htaccess to:

```
RewriteRule    ^([a-z]{2})/$     /main.php?lang=$1    [L,E=no_more_redirect:1]

<If "env('no_more_redirect')   != 1">
Redirect 301   /main.php        /en/
</If>
```

-> **How it is supposed to work** and solve my problem:

1. When apache gets my `/main.php` request, it applies the redirect
2. when it receive my `/en/` request, it rewrites the url into `/main.php?=lang=en`, and sets `no_more_redirect` to 1
3. when it tries to apply all the rules and redirect directives, it doesn't apply "`Redirect 301 /main.php /en/`" anymore.
4. It treats the `/main.php?lang=en` request.
5. YAY! but it doesn't work. x(

here is the error log I get when trying to reach `/main.php` with this solution: ah, I can't post more than 2 links because I have less than 10 reputation, but **here is basically what happens**:

1. it gets my `/main.php` request
2. it redirects me to `/en/`
3. it rewrites `/en/` into `/main.php?lang=en` AND sets `no_more_redirect` to 1
4. but when it checks the condition, it gives 1 when it should give 0, and then the redirection gets applied for the second time. **Fail.**

The thing is, I don't really know the syntax of the `<if>` tag, and the doc (see here: can't post more than 2 links :c) is not very clear. Also, I don't really know the differences between environment variables and server variables and I've seen over the internet, some things like `<if %{name_of_variable}` and `<if env('name_of_variable')` and I don't know which one is one, and how to use them etc...

also, you must know I clear my browser's cache between every try, otherwise it behave in a weird manner.

### solution I tryed number 2 : REQUEST_URL

I tried to use `%{REQUEST_URI}` which contains the URL given (see here: again I can't post more than 2 links...) like

```
<if "%{REQUEST_URI} != '/en/'">
Redirect 301   /main.php        /en/
</If>
```

But what happens is that when apache gets the `/en/` request and checks the `<if>` condition, it gives 0 (which is the expected behaviour), but when apache rewrites `/en/` into `/main.php?lang=en` and tries to apply the rewrite rules and redirect directives, `%{REQUEST_URI}` changes, and when apache checks the condition `<if>` condition, it gives 1, and `/main.php` gets replaced by `/en/`, giving `/en/?lang=en`. **Fail again.**

### Solution I tried number3 : IS_SUBREQ

While looking for a solution, I read here : (can't post more than two links :c), that the variable `IS_SUBREQ` is to `true` if the request being treated is a sub request (request created for a module to work fine). I thought, when apache splits `/main.php?lang=en` in `/main.php` and `args=lang=en`, to try and apply the rules and directives, I thought, that must be a subrequest. So I tryed:

```
<If "%{IS_SUBREQ} != 'true'">
Redirect 301 /main.php  /en/
</If>
```

But in fact, even after the URL splitting, `IS_SUBREQ` never gets to false, and the evaluation of expression (when it checks the if condition) always give 1. Thus, this solution is a **failure**.

That's why I am posting a question here.
Thank you for reading such a long post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, my problem was hiding another one, the real problem is a loop problem here, but thanks to the args the loop stops on its first (but one too much) utterance. I had to search for "rewrite rule redirect loop" and I found the answer very quickly here : [.htaccess redirect loop when Redirect and RewriteRule together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102978/htaccess-redirect-loop-when-redirect-and-rewriterule-together).
To apply this solution to my problem, I had to use the rewrite_mod to make 301 redirections, and set a `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200` on it. The thing is, I still don't know how this works. It does, but I don't know why. Why does REDIRECT_STATUS gets to 200 when the /en/ URL gets rewrote? But I guess this is no place to ask this question.